# How to run script remotely?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops

I have 3 different applications running in AWS under one AWS account with 3 ec2 instances each which mean I have 9 ec2 instances having 9 java process, how can I kill java process running in multiple ec2 machines remotely?

What I want to do is to run a command from bastion host which can ssh into one machine or all the machines and stop the java process instead of ssh into all machines

Comment: You can use AWS System Manager's Remote Execution to do this. Please refer this [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/remotely-run-commands-ec2-instance-systems-manager/)

Answer (score 0):

This could be done via bash script.

Bash script allows you to automate the steps that you would normally type into the terminal manually. You also need to [create ssh-key](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2) so that the script can ssh login into the instance on your manner, and you would need to do this for all of your instances individually. To ensure that you have set things up right, you can try logging in `ssh user@yourhost` and there's should be no password prompt.

Once you have all the ssh-key setup between your bastation host and the 9 instances, you can write a script on your bastation host, and the script may goes something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@yourhost1 <<EOF
  #kill your java process
EOF

ssh user@yourhost2 <<EOF
  #kill your java process
EOF
```

Basically, any commands that go in between << EOF and EOF, will be executed on your remote host.

Alternatively, you could use [`loop` statement](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-loops.php) for the 9 instances.

I hope my answer gives you some clues and you find it useful.